# AJAX POST requests with JQuery don't urlencode '+'

Tags: jquery, json, encoding

I have a lot of JSON data I need to pass to a request:

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://"+HOST+"/users/rankings",
                data: "friends="+JSON.stringify(friendsArr),
                success: function(response){
                    $("#rankings").html(response);
                }
            });
```

friendsArr is an array of objects in JSON format.  The issue is that some objects have data with a "+" and that does not get encoded properly.  It comes in server side as a " " and the data is messed up.  Do I really have to iterate through all the data and encode each value separately? There must be an easier way.

Comment: What is `friendsArr` exactly?

Comment: an array of JSON objects

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would try it using the `$.post` method vs. the raw `$.ajax` one, and let jQuery handle the work for you:

```
$.post( "http://"+HOST+"/users/rankings",
    { friends: JSON.stringify(friendsArr) },
    function(data){
        $("#rankings").html(response);
  }
);
```

Additionally, since you can only `POST` via AJAX to addresses on the same domain, why not just use `"/users/rankings"` as your URL vs. `"http://"+HOST+"/users/rankings"`

Comment: the post was not necessary (although not a bad idea) but doing friends: as opposed to "friends=" did it.  i guess that tells jquery to escape the data and set the content-type properly... also thanks for reminding me about no need for domain!

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to use the javascript `escape` function to fix this problem.   Just escape your data and URL before you send it off.

Comment: @Tony what happens when you escape the data?  The `+` still comes back as a space, or it comes back as something else?   You'll probably have to decode it in your serverside code.

Comment: correct, comes in as a " ".  i am actually using rails so it should decode automatically...or else i think i would be getting some crazy errors

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it as easy as:

```
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
    url: "http://"+HOST+"/users/rankings",
    data: "friends="+escape(JSON.stringify(friendsArr)),
    success: function(response){
        $("#rankings").html(response);
    }
});
```